# CSS inline-grid shows wrong size in Layout develop tool

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a simple
`.grid{display:inline-grid; width:400px; height: 300px; grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 3fr}` grid box 3 child items inside.
It supposed to be
1fr:50px height to .item:nth-child(1)
2fr:100px height to .item:nth-child(2)
3fr:150px height to .item:nth-child(3)

But as of the screenshot, it shows smaller, and the width display 320px instead of 400px.
Anyone knows what's wrong?
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Grid</title>
        <style>
            .grid {
                display: inline-grid;
                height: 300px;
                width: 400px;
                background-color: rgb(231, 173, 173);
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 3fr;
            }
            .item:nth-child(2n) {
                background-color: rgb(140, 226, 172);
            }
            .item:nth-child(2n + 1) {
                background-color: rgb(140, 160, 226);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Added, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Where do you see 320px?
I check in my browser and it shows 400px.

Comment: Check the image I uploaded, right bottom, there is a Layout, and check the div.grid. I asked one of my friend check on her computer, it shows correct as well, It may casue by my browser, but I have no idea...

Comment: I checked it in latest Chrome and Edge, both have same issue.

Comment: Maybe change the dimensions on the top of the page to something bigger then 356

Comment: I figured out, it actually screen scale issue, my Dell laptop was 125%scale as recommoned, I changed to 100%scale, it shows correct now.